# Why does text added to areatext by page refresh , not directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nicedit

I have [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/) to get `areatext` as editor.

```
 <select id="greetings" name="greetings">
      <option value="" selected>Select one </option>
      <option value="1" onClick="addGreeting('text1'); return false;">text1</option>
      <option value="2" onClick="addGreeting('text2'); return false;">text2</option>
      <option value="3" onClick="addGreeting('text3'); return false;">text3</option>
    </select>
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="8" ></textarea>
```

So when user select option it will be inserted to textarea automatically.

Here the javascript code

```
 bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);

   function addGreeting(text) {
text = ' ' + text + ' ';
if (document.sc_form.message.createTextRange && document.sc_form.message.caretPos) {
    var caretPos = document.sc_form.message.caretPos;
    caretPos.text = caretPos.text.charAt(caretPos.text.length - 1) == ' ' ? text + ' ' : text;
    document.sc_form.message.focus();
} else {
document.sc_form.message.value  += text;
document.sc_form.message.focus();
}
  }
```

**OBS** without niceditor everything works perfect , the option selected will be inserted directly.
 **BUT** not it inserted only when i refresh the page.

And i want that text will be inserted without refresh.

If someone is interested about the order of script here is my order

```
<script src="submit.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="include/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
```

Anything else let me know and i insert it ,thanks for taking time with my code.

**EDIT:**

here my [**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/38uLe/3/) //this not working with the editor plugin.

this [**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Rkt/320/) // this works without the plugin

--
i think the problem is with `bkLib.onDomLoaded` thats why maybe the text is inserted after the page load(refresh) , any suggest on how to replace it ?

Comment: you can insert new button into nicedit pretty easily you should look into that instead

Comment: [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/) is a script ,which convert textarea to an editor, i cant add button inside editor.

Comment: niecdit is a script that i'm using in my projects & it is real easy to add cutom button to it read the api, do your research http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/516/Creating%20a%20Plugin also nicedit works on any html element not just on textarea...

Comment: edited my answer again ,

Comment: You need this code to do it. ` $(".nicEdit-main").append("works");`

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with nicedit

nicedit as 100% of wysiwyg is modifying the dom upon instantiation, hiding your textarea or whatever html element to be edited

- either you learn nicedit API and you create a custom button/dropdown to append your text
- either you destroy the instance upon change event (`.removeInstance()`), append your text to your editable then re-instantiate editor

the clean solution is the first one, the lazy solution the second